# I am getting an error like below how can i solve it?

Tags: postgresql

```
select into Users( User_ID,Name,LastName,UserName,DateOfBirth,Password)
valuse('1','Ensar','isci','ensarisci','21/08/2000','120761');
select*from Users;
```

```
ERROR: HATA:  "("  yerinde söz dizim hatası 
LINE 1: select into Users(User_ID,name,LastName,UserName,DateOfBirth...
                         ^
SQL state: 42601
Character: 18
```

Comment: Do you mean `insert into`? And `values`?

Answer (score 0):

Correct way to to insert:

```
insert into Users( User_ID,Name,LastName,UserName,DateOfBirth,Password)
values('1','Ensar','isci','ensarisci','21/08/2000','120761');
select*from Users;
```

> https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp

Comment: You're not inserting data from the select but only inserting a single row and in a separated query selecting on `users`. I fail to see how this is the answer.

Comment: He hasn't yet specified that he wants to select the data and insert, question was this is the error which is syntax so I think I answered the question asked